# Eslint blocking commit, terminal is stuck on "running eslint..." forever

Tags: reactjs, git, eslint, commit

I'm working on react project which has integrated eslint. It works great and if I try commit code that is not compatible with eslint i get errors and commit is stopped. Although when I don't have any errors I just get message "running eslint...". I tried waiting, but after an hour I decided to break by ctrl-c and commit with --no-verify flag. It happens both in vscode on Ubuntu as in Intellij on Windows.
Has any encountered this problem before and know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you look in the `.git/hooks` directory and find the relevant hook (probably `pre-commit`) and include its contents as a code block in your question?

Comment: Try to add the `--debug` flag to the eslint command ran by the git hook. It should give you more info on what's going on.

Answer (score 6):

Have encountered the same issue and the solution for me was to remove the build directory and it works

Comment: Yup, looks like ESLint started processing the `build` directory as well. An alternative to always deleting it is to create a `.eslintignore` file with `build/` inside.

Comment: In my case it needed to ignore `coverage/`

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that `storybook_static` build files will too make eslint hang forever :/
Just remove it too.

Comment: This one saves. Basically the answer was to remove build folder. But I missed this folder, and this comment saves me.

Comment: or storybook-static in my case :)